# What is the isotypic decomposition of $S^*(End(V))$ as a $GL(V) \times GL(V)$ module?

Tags: linear-algebra, representation-theory, symmetric-groups, algebraic-groups

Let $V$ be a vector space over $F$. Consider $End(V)$ as $H = GL(V) \times GL(V)$ module, via conjugation. ($(A,B)$ sends $S \in End(V)$ to $ASB^{-1}$.)

$End(V)$ is irreducible over $H = GL(V) \times GL(V)$, since it is tensor product of two irreducible $GL(V)$ modules. I want to know about the isotypic decomposition of the coordinate ring $S^*(End(V)^*)$, because of the motivation below. It also seems like a natural thing to think about. Hints would be welcome, or references.

I would also be happy to know whether or not isomorphic irreducibles can appear as submodules of $S^k(End(V))$ and $S^j(End(V))$ for different $k$ and $j$. This is an easier question and would also solve the problem in my motivation.

Thoughts: 
$S^k(V^* \otimes V)$ we can rewrite as $((V^*)^{\otimes k} \otimes V^{\otimes k})^{S_k}$.

Inside of this is $S^k(V^*) \otimes S^k(V)$, which is irreducible over $GL(V) \times GL(V)$. These are just the tensors which are (independently) invariant in each of the first $k$ and last $k$ factors,so there is more in $S^k(End(V))$. (The invariant tensor $f_1 \otimes f_2 \otimes v_1 \otimes v_2 + f_2 \otimes f_1 \otimes v_2 \otimes v_1$ is  not in $S^2(V^*) \otimes S^2(V)$, for example.) (Or one could do a quick dimension count.)

I guess that the remaining irreducible submodules in $S^k(V^*)$ have to do with the way that $S_k$ invariance can be spread over the two factors. I don't know how to make this precise though.

Motivation: I'm trying to show that an irreducible polynomial representation of $GL(V)$ on a space $W$ has matrix coefficients which are homogeneous forms, all of the same degree. So I am looking at the map $End(W)^* \to S^*(End(V)^*)$, induced by pullback of the induced map $End(V) \to End(W)$ (my representation is polynomial). $End(W)^*$ is an irreducible $GL(V) \times GL(V)$ module, and this pullback map is $GL(V) \times GL(V)$ equivariant (well, I think so, I did the computation but maybe I'm wrong - in general, it seems that if $\psi : G \to H$ is a homomorphism of affine algebraic groups, then for the induced $G \times G$ actions on the coordinate rings, by left and right multiplication on $H$, the pullback map is $G \times G$ equivariant. The proof of equivariance just amounts to the observation that $f \psi(g_1 g g^{-1}_2) = f ( \psi(g_1) \psi(g) \psi(g_2)^{-1})$.)

I would like to show that each isotypic component of $S^*(End(V))$ lives some $S^k(End(V))$, or that if $k \not = j$, $S^k(End(V))$ and $S^j(End(V))$ have no irreducibles in common. That would force $\phi$ to land in some $S^k(End(V)^*$, which would prove that the matrix coefficients are all homogeneous of degree $k$. (I guess that there is an easier proof of this exercise, and I'd be open to a suggestion.)

Comment: If $F$ has positive characteristic, the representation you are looking at is not semisimple. Do you intend this to be part of the complication, or would you prefer to think first about the characteristic $0$ case (where an explicit answer is actually well-known)?

Comment: @Stephen I didn't know that. I would definitely be happy to learn a characteristic zero result about the decomposition. Why does semisimplicity fail in positive characteristic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you instead consider $S^*(V \otimes W)$ as a $GL(V)\times GL(W)$ module, the thing to google is "Howe duality". Understanding the representation you want should just be a special case where $W=V^*$.

As for your question of whether or not isomorphic irreducibles can appear in different symmetric powers the answer is no.  To see this it is enough to look at it as a module just over one copy of $GL(V)$, let's say the left one.

This copy of $GL(V)$ is only acting on the left factor of $V \otimes V^*$, and in particular as a representation of this copy of $GL(V)$ this is just a direct sum of $\dim(V)$ copies of $V$.  But now it's clear that $S^k(V\otimes V^*)$ is a degree $k$ representation of this copy of $GL(V)$, and hence $S^k(V\otimes V^*)$ and $S^j(V\otimes V^*)$ have no common factors.